# Where is the P_Drive in the Macintosh EVE-Online Client?

Tags: macos, eve-online

The P_Drive used to be in ~user/Preferences/EVE Online Preferences/

It's been moved since sometime in 2011. Where is the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They moved it to ~user/Library/Application Support/Eve Online/

Since Spotlight does not search the Library folder, this was very hard to find. I've placed it here on gaming.stackexchange so it might help others.